# how to convert 1,800.00 to 1800 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert `1,100.00` or `1,800.00` to `1100` or `1800` by using Javascript Number() function but it gives `NaN`.
For Example:

```
var num = "1,100.00";
console.log(Number(num));

output: NaN
```

My requirement is If I have a number 1,800.00 it should convert to 1800 in Javascript.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove commas first.

Comment: The comma comes dynamically from input.

Comment: Then you can still remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Number() function converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value. If the value cannot be converted to a legal number, NaN is returned.

You might have multiple `,` in the string replace all `,` from the string before passing to `Number()`:

```js
let numStr = '1,800.00';
let num = Number(numStr.replace(/,/g,''));
console.log(num);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mamun, It's working.

Comment: @GufranHasan, you are most welcome.....

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the `,` char using *built-in* `replace` function and then just convert to `Number`.

```js
let number = "1,100.00";
console.log(Number(number.replace(',','')));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut, It's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the `,` with empty `''` and then convert the string into number with `+` operator

```js
let neu = "6,100.00";
document.write(+neu.replace(',',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
var myValue = '1,800.00';
var myNumber = myValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
var result = Math.abs(myNumber);
console.log( Math.floor(myNumber))
```

Here, in `myValue`, only number is taken removing other characters except dot.
Next thing is the value is converted to positive number using Math.abs method.
And at last using Math.floor function the fraction part is removed.